# Weird Bug with SVG Filters in CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, svg-filters, css-filters

I am currently try to find the best way to lazy-load images. While loading I want to show a tiny 10x10 image of the original (inline / base64). As this tiny image, of cause has a very poor quality I need to blur it, until the original high resolution image is loaded. Unfortunately the default CSS-filter blur() adds this white-area around the images which I want to avoid.

For that reason, I searched and found this SVG filter to make blur images without bright borders.

Unfortunately I have this crazy weird appearance on my Mac with Chrome. Same on other MacBooks. Didn't test on Windows. In Safari and in Chrome on iPhone I don't see the filter at all.

Do you have any idea how to get control of this problem?

```css
img {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' aria-labelledby='title desc'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter id='blur' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='20' edgeMode='duplicate' /%3E%3CfeComponentTransfer%3E%3CfeFuncA type='discrete' tableValues='1 1' /%3E%3C/feComponentTransfer%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E#blur");
   margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img 
    class="highres  " 
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520206183501-b80df61043c2?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2251&q=80" height="600"
        
>
```

https://codepen.io/flexplosion/pen/abBdeRo

[image]

Comment: if you have a very small image and you want to blur it use `image-rendering: crisp-edges;` Please check this article: /css-tricks: [image-rendering](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/)

Comment: @enxaneta Switched everything to this image-rendering which seems to be perfect. Especially with this option pixelated which can be, depending on the website, very cool too I think.

Want to create it as an answer?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. I'll be glad to upvote it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have semi-transparent anti-aliasing around the image which the filter you're using is converting to fully opaque so you're getting weird colors. If you alter the parameters for tableValues - it will solve your issues.

```css
img {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' aria-labelledby='title desc'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter id='blur' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='20' edgeMode='duplicate' /%3E%3CfeComponentTransfer%3E%3CfeFuncA type='discrete' tableValues='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1' /%3E%3C/feComponentTransfer%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E#blur");
   margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img 
    class="highres  " 
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520206183501-b80df61043c2?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2251&q=80" height="600"
        
>
```